# Adding Tabs to text boxes within a webpage?

Tags: keyboard, text, web-browser

**Is there a way to type a tab space to text within a webpage?**
(without copy pasting a tab)

The normal behaviour of the tab key in an internet browser is cycling between input fields, buttons links etc but now with online document edotors (like Google Docs), how can a user add a *tab* to a document?

Answer (score 1):

Normally option-tab would do that, but it doesn't work in web views. As a workaround, you could create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`.

```
{
    "~t" = insertTabIgnoringFieldEditor:; /* option-t */
}
```